# I can't edit css font size

Tags: html, css

i have a problem. [image]

Whatever i do, i can't change the font size. I'm already using font-size: 1em; or font-size: 100px; but not being change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its look like you are tring to add it inside a any media screen as I can see the curly bracket at the end.

Comment: u can see on link zafernci.xyz/uploadd

Comment: .button-btn {
    background: #409fff;
    border: 1px solid #409fff;
    border-radius: 5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Darker Grotesque', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    /* height: 2.5em; */
    left: 50%;
    outline: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /* width: 9.75em; */
}

Comment: use the above style inside the btton-btn. Dont use width and height, just simply use padding perporty.

Comment: your code are working but button position has gone xd look at to my website again

Comment: use the following code in your CSS and update it

.panel_footer {
    top: 21.4em;
    border-top: 1px solid #bfc3c5;
    height: 4.5em;
    padding: 0 1.25em;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button-btn {
    background: #409fff;
    border: 1px solid #409fff;
    border-radius: 5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Darker Grotesque', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 10px 60px;
}

Comment: I have used flex properties there. So remove the position styles from button-btn.

Comment: done, ohh finally. thank you soooooo much <3

Answer (score -1):

Try:

- Find if the class in HTML is wrong, like, you are actually using #button-btn but not .button-btn.
- Try go with !important.

Anyway, it is suggested that you post the html.

---

The real problem I think: you are using em for width and height. Use rem instead.

Comment: font-size: 1em; code is working but just changing all button size, i just want change size font size

Comment: I don't think you are describing it clearly as your question said the code is not working... But in my own comprehension the button may be too small or the text is contained under another class. I don't have your html and cannot answer.

Comment: I've found the problem: you are using em for the width and height param, you should change them to rem because em is based on font's size. I think it solves the problem.

Comment: a min, i'm trying

Comment: i did change as "font-size:2rem;" but still same, changing all button size

Comment: You misunderstood. Change width and height parameter's em to rem for the element.